# print the first sentence of each paragraph in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file and wish to print the ***first*** sentence of each paragraph.  Paragraphs are separated by a line break, i.e. "\n".

From the BreakIterator, I thought I could use the getLineInstance() for this but it seems it is iterator over each word:

```
public String[] extractFirstSentences() {
    BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getLineInstance(Locale.US);
    boundary.setText(getText());

    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    int start = boundary.first();
    int end = boundary.next();
    while (end != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        String sentence = getText().substring(start, end).trim();
        if (!sentence.isEmpty()) {
            sentences.add(sentence);
        }
        start = end;
        end = boundary.next();
    }

    return sentences.toArray(new String[sentences.size()]);
```

Am I using getLineInstance() incorrectly or is there another method to do what I want?

Comment: What constitutes a "sentence"? How would it handle stuff like "Will Dr. Brown be joining us?"

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use the `getSentenceIterator`?

Comment: As defined by BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(), not sure how it is implemented by I'm assuming it is using a period followed by at least a single space as the separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this as an alternative:

```
public String[] extractFirstSentences() {
    String myText = getText();
    String[] paragraphs = myText.split("\\n");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String paragraph : paragraphs) {
        result.add(paragraph.split("[\\.\\?\\!][\\r\\n\\t ]+")[0] + ".");
    }

    return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have to go this route.  Still a bit disappointed that getLineInstance() is not working as intended, or maybe I'm not applying it correctly.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: Bit cheeky, after the OP expressed that he's not entirely satisfied..